# Deploying dlls to GAC

Tags: .net, sharepoint, dll, gac

We have a Sharepoint 2010 solution that we are trying to the deploy to the production environment.

We have developed this solution using Visual Studio 2010 and we have created several projects which result in a number of dlls.

We are getting the following error when accessing one of the web parts.

> An error occurred during the compilation of the requested file, or one
>   of its dependencies. The type 'xxxx' is defined in an assembly that is
>   not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'xxx,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxx'.

For installing the dlls - I have dragged and dropped them into the GAC.
Is this a good approach? Could it be the cause of the problem? perhaps there is a better way of installing into the GAC? Or perhaps they need to be installed in a particular order?? The one without dependencies first?

This is the full error from the log file:

System.Web.HttpCompileException: c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6f2f2743\7b5d4663\App_Web_rxpractioncommonwpusercontrol.ascx.12f7e65c.q7c1p6i0.0.cs(134): error CS0012: The type 'xxxx' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'xxxx, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=fe560f99f37381ef'.    at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.Compile()     at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild()     at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath)     at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildI...    a47a805d-765d-429e-b080-fe031b3e4fac

Thanks,

Joseph

Comment: Is this a programming question or an installation question? You might be better off asking this on ServerFault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you mention that you already tried deploying the assemblies from WSP, I thought I would list another possibility as a new answer. You are going to need to be specific about which assembly is missing first of all, and then validate that this assembly is present in the GAC of all your front ends. You need to rule out any possibility that the reference assembly actually is missing. Use the fusion log viewer as was mentioned in another answer.

Next, how was your web part developed and are you sure its the web part throwing that error? Specifically, are you using any .ascx markup in your web part to reference controls out of this 'missing' assembly? If so, you may need to be sure to add a `<%@ Assembly Name="" %>` directive to your markup so that the asp.net compiler knows to reference it during compilation. You may potentially need to add SafeControl entries also.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. I will use fusion log viewer to investigate this.

Comment: Just to give some more background about the error ... The dll is a class library that has our business entities. This is strongly typed and in our development environment it works without issues. However, to make it work ... I needed to add the following entry in the web.config (under assemblies).         <add assembly="xxxxx, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=fe560f99f37381ef" />

Comment: Without this entry it would give the error I stated in the question.  However, when I added the entry in the production environment, it still gave the error. The error is in the compilation.

Comment: I have added the erorr to the question. Thanks

Comment: seeing your error log it is indeed as i suspected, you are using ascx markup in your webpart. please try adding the `<%@ Assembly %>` directive to your .ascx to properly reference the assembly without the web.config entry. did you also verify that the assembly is present on all the web front ends after the wsp deployment?

Comment: Yes - assembly is correct on both front ends. That is a very good point you are mentioning regarding add the assemblies in the markup as I have noticed that sharepoint does this. For example, there is Microsoft.Web.Command as an assembly. I will add this and give it a try on our test environment. However, I will have to wait till tomorrow to try it on the live environment. I will reply back to this thread. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Approach work on our test environment. Many thanks. Will try it on the live servers, later today

Comment: It worked!! adding the assembly reference solved. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 5):

You should be creating WSP packages with Visual Studio 2010 for your SharePoint 2010 solutions. You could include the referenced assemblies as part of your main package. To do this, double click on the Package in your SharePoint project, and go to the advanced tab. From here you will be able include external assemblies into your WSP, or automatically include the output from other projects in your solution.

If you are referencing assemblies which could be shared by multiple WSP solutions, be careful of this particular caveat: When a WSP is retracted, all included assemblies in the WSP are also retracted regardless of whether or not another WSP also includes the assembly.

My recommended best practice for a shared assembly is to create a standalone WSP solution which contains nothing but the assemblies. Create a new empty SharePoint project. Click on the project in the Solution Explorer, and view the properties pane using F4. Set "Include assembly in package" to false and "Assembly Deployment Target" to GlobalAssemblyCache. Then double click on the package, and go to the advanced tab to add your assembly references.

You will end up with more than one WSP to deploy your solution, but this helps deal with dependencies in a reliable way.

You should never use manually adding assemblies to the GAC as your production deployment method!!

Comment: Many Thanks for your detailed reply. I will go ahead with the WSP for deploying to GAC. will let you know how it goes...

Comment: one question - If I set the  "Include assembly in package" to false, than "Assembly Deployment Target" is disabled and I cannot set it up.  Could you kindly advise?

Comment: I do not really think that "Assembly Deployment Target" to GlobalAssemblyCache is needed because that is the actual dll for the project and I do not need this in the GAC

Comment: I have packaged the dlls in the WSP and re-installed the wsp ... but still receiving the same error!

Comment: You are correct, I apologize. The Assembly Deployment Target is only for the actual dll of the project and you do not need this just to use the WSP for packing other dlls. Since you are still have errors, I have posted a new answer with different suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

The preferred way of getting assemblies into the GAC would be with an application installer :) Note that you need elevated privileges to install assemblies to the GAC. You can also use gacutil.

Order of GAC'ing assemblies shouldn't matter.

As per the error, you might be missing a prerequisite assembly - use [FusLogVw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx) or a tool like Reflector to determine which dependencies aren't deploying.

Comment: Thaks for your reply. I will try to get more info and what dll is causing the problem and proceed from there.

Comment: Yes, Fusion log viewer is a great tool to determine which assembly was missed. However I would recommend against the use of gacutil for production SharePoint deployments. If there are multiple front ends, you would have to take care to take the same steps on each one and that is prone to human error. The SharePoint WSP is designed for exactly this.