# How can I remove the tables rendered around the webparts in the Rich Content area?

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts

How would I override the tables rendered around the webparts in the "Rich Content" area?

I have successfully removed the tables around webpartzones and their webparts but can't figure how to remove the tables around Rich Content area webparts.

I am not using the Content Editor WebPart.

The "Rich Content" area I am using is created using the PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField.

This is the control which has content and webparts.

Bounty [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/32193/how-can-i-remove-the-tables-rendered-around-the-webparts-in-the-rich-content-are).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it:
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/32957/7442

Answer (score 0):

I have pondered this myself in the past and I've come up with two options, though none are very appealing, so have not implemented them:

1. Create a custom rich text field. Override render, call base.Render using a TextWriter object and place the resulting html in a variable, which you then "manually" clean up, before writing to output.
2. Create a custom rich text field. Override render, but instead of calling base.Render, take care of the magic of inserting the webparts yourself. (This is probably trickier.)

Good luck!

Update, some example code I use to minimize the output of the RichHtmlField:

```
public class SlimRichHtmlField : RichHtmlField
{

    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter output)
    {
        if (IsEdit() == false)
        {
            //This will remove the label which precedes the bodytext which identifies what
            //element this is. This is also identified using the aria-labelledby attribute
            //used by for example screen readers. In our application, this is not needed.
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);

            HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

            base.Render(htw);
            htw.Flush();                
            string replaceHtml = GetReplaceHtml();
            string replaceHtmlAttr = GetReplaceHtmlAttr();
            sb.Replace(replaceHtml, string.Empty).Replace(replaceHtmlAttr, string.Empty);
            output.Write(sb.ToString());                
        }
        else
        {
            base.Render(output);
        }
    }

    private string GetReplaceHtmlAttr()
    {
        return " aria-labelledby=\"" + this.ClientID + "_label\"";
    }

    private string GetReplaceHtml()
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("<div id=\"" + this.ClientID + "_label\" style='display:none'>");
        if (this.Field != null)
        {
            sb.Append(SPHttpUtility.HtmlEncode(this.Field.Title));
        }
        else
        {
            sb.Append(SPHttpUtility.HtmlEncode(SPResource.GetString("RTELabel", new object[0])));
        }
        sb.Append("</div>");

        return sb.ToString();
    }

    private bool IsEdit()
    {
        return SPContext.Current.FormContext.FormMode == SPControlMode.Edit || SPContext.Current.FormContext.FormMode == SPControlMode.New;
    }
}
```

This code is then used by your pagelayout like this:

```
<YourPrefix:SlimRichHtmlField ID="RichHtmlField1" HasInitialFocus="false" MinimumEditHeight="200px" FieldName="PublishingPageContent" runat="server" />
```

Comment: Wouldn't creating a custom rich text field make the editor in the ribbon useless? Why can't I override the settings of the Rich Content area.

Comment: Not if you inherit from the default RichHtmlField, and just override Render in that class.

Comment: How would I actually do that. Theory is nice.

Comment: I updated now with some example code I use to clean up the output. I'm sure you can go on from there

Comment: Should I add that c# code the app_code folder? How do i get it registered on the page layout?

Comment: You should compile the dll, sign it with a strong name and deploy it to the GAC folder, preferable using a WSP. See this thread for more info on how to do that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238433/deploying-dlls-to-gac
Then you can use it on your aspx-page like any webcontrol, by first registering the Namespace and tagprefix and then place it in markup like I did last in my example.